# how to create a better search algorithm than just simple match and search

Tags: php, algorithm

what algorithm will be best suited for the following situation:

Suppose the user enters in search box :- Dell Computers
But in the database this term doesn't exist but what exist is :- Dell 
or just :-Computers
so how/what alogrithm can work for the above scenario.
Steps required:

```
1) Find to see if an exact match exists for "Dell Computers"
2) If not, then check for each word like "Dell" and "Computers"
```

Moreover i want to implement this in PHP. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: can you try MATCH() AGAINST() function? (SQL part)

Comment: Unclear what you want to get here. You already have your algorithm that consist of 2 steps. And what do you mean by "better"? Better in what sense? Usually  database has own implementation of search queries, so you don't have to write your own "match and search"

Comment: by algorithm i mean the proper way..to do implement this in a programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been done extensively in the area of [Full text searching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search). Look at [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/), [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch), [MySQL Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html), or [PostgreSQL Full Text Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html).

The basic idea is to create a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of single keywords pointing to the resulting set of articles/documents, then look up each word separately and do a set intersection of the results to find articles matching both - and fall back on the individual result sets if there are no good intersections.

Add to that [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) of the lookup words, and you're on your way to reimplementing Lucene and friends.